# Word for mirror reflecting mirror infinitely?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word for a mirror reflecting another mirror infinitely? I.e. if two mirrors are put one against another, how would I call it (or if there is no word for it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to summon up that image for most readers would be a reference to a **hall of mirrors**. If you want to talk about that effect, you might say *hall-of-mirrors effect* (though a quick Google search tells me this has specific connotations in the programming world).

Comment: Another name given to the same thing is *house of mirrors*.

Comment: Or Fun-House Mirrors.

Comment: Aren't funhouse mirrors more the type than make you skinny/fat/distorted/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

"Mise en abyme" is the French phrase but I think very usable in English poetry or prose:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme

Answer (score 1):

You might say they were *infinitely regressive*, although that's a term generally used in logic.

Comment: "Infinitely regressive" would be good, but I need it to be a little more poetic (sorry for not mentioning that in the question).

Answer (score 1):

A year late and a dollar short. I found your thread trying to remember the word. Hint of the day: it's out there.

The word we were both looking for is "recursive" or "recursion".

Comment: Perhaps *reciprocal recursive*, but *recursive* on its own means that the mirror would create this effect alone.

Answer (score 0):

How about "mirrorrim"? Not a real word as far as I know, but don't let that stop you.

Comment: Too bad I have to translate it to Lithuanian.. :)

Comment: In laser physics we call it a resonant optical cavity, but that's not very poetic either.

Answer (score -1):

"recursive" or "recursion" doesn't really indicate the affect which is "reflection" - so... compound

Recursiflection???

Remove the prefix and compound

Cursiflection???

Remove the suffix 'sive'

Recurflection???

change the tence?

Recurflect??? Recurflected???

Drop the prefix??? (Again?) :)

Curflection???

I come up with Curflection 'the multiple images of a mirrors own reflection' OR

Re-curflection 'the repeating image of a mirrors own reflection/(Curflection)'

A slightly educated and researched guess :)

Comment: I have to ask: since *recursive* does not work, why is it your starting point? Why not start with *generous*, or *amaranthine*, or *Karl Marx*? They don't work just as well. If a word does not fit, the solution is to drop it, not to rape it.

Comment: Also, do read up on all the terms you are throwing around. You can't change the tense of a noun. A noun *has* no tense.

Comment: In addition, I believe you mean ["effect" not "affect"](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/affect-versus-effect).